# http request to a different app in a different port

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have 2 nodejs apps one running in port 8000 that only returns "hello"
and another app running on port 3000 that makes a simple http request to the first app

```
var http = require('http');
var r = http.get({
    host: 'localhost',
    path: '/',
    port: '8000'
    },
    function(response) {
        var body = '';
        response.on('data', function(d) {
            body += d;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            console.log(body);
        });
    });
```

the console log returns

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

What´s the problem here?
the first app is running correctly in http://localhost:8000/ but for some reason
when the second app makes a request to the first app I get the error I posted above. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like first app (on port 8000) is not reachable or not started at the moment, when second app sends request.

Comment: yes. I want to know why. both apps are running at the same time. thanks